# Can I edit a previously-made gradient in Gimp?

Tags: gimp

I made a gradient in a layer in Gimp, then moved onto other things. Can I return to the mode like when I was editing the gradient and I was modifying the control points inside the image canvas? Or once I leave the gradient it becomes permanent?

Comment: No. Gradients are not editable once applied. Instead, put the gradient fill on a new layer. That way if you need to change it you can delete the layer, make a new one, and apply another gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the gradient has been rendered and you leave the Blend tool the gradient becomes permanent.

The last gradient you used/edited in the Blend tool in the current editing session is saved under the name `Custom` (and is the first gradient in the list).

Comment: is this still true as of GIMP 2.8?

Comment: No because you cannot alter the gradient in the blend tool in 2.8. The 2.10 UI is vastly superiorto the 2.8 one.